# How to use ODBC to link SQL database and do SQL queries in Python

Tags: python, sql, r, odbc

I usually use R to do SQL queries by using ODBC to link to a SQL database. The code generally looks like this:

```
library(RODBC)
ch<-odbcConnect('B1P HANA',uid='****',pwd='****')
myOffice <- c(0)
office_clause = ""
if (myOffice != 0) {
  office_clause = paste(
    'AND "_all"."/BIC/ZSALE_OFF" IN (',paste(myOffice, collapse=", "),')'
  )
}
a <- sqlQuery(ch,paste(' SELECT "_all"."CALDAY" AS "ReturnDate                         FROM "SAPB1P"."/BIC/AZ_RT_A212" "_all"
                         WHERE "_all"."CALDAY"=20180101
                               ',office_clause,'
                         GROUP BY "_all"."CALDAY
                       '))
```

The workflow is:

1. odbcConnect is to link R and SQL using ODBC.
2. myOffice is an array for achieving data from R. Those data will be used as filter conditions in WHERE clause in SQL.
3. a stores the query result from SQL database.

So, how to do all of these in Python, i.e., do SQL queries in Python by using ODBC to link SQL database and Python? I am new to Python. All I know is like:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=B1P HANA;UID=****;PWD=****')
```

Then I do not know how to continue. And I cannot find an overall example online. Could anyone help by providing a comprehensive example? From link SQL database in Python unitl retrieving the result?

Comment: This could be a place to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49247884/querying-from-microsoft-sql-to-a-pandas-dataframe/49250361#49250361 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Execute SQL from python

Instantiate a Cursor and use the execute method of the Cursor class to execute any SQL statement.

```
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

### Select

You can use `fetchall`, `fetchone`, and `fetchmany` to retrieve rows returned from SELECT statements:

```
import pyodbc

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=myDSN;UID=***;PWD=***')
cursor.execute("SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM MyTable WHERE Col1= 'SomeValue'")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
  print(row.Col1, row.Col2 )
```

You can provide parameterized queries in a sequence or in the argument list:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ... FROM MyTable WHERE Col1 = ?", 'SomeValue',1)
```

### Insert

INSERT commands also use the `execute` method; however, you must subsequently call the `commit` method after an insert or you will lose your changes:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1) VALUES ('SomeValue')")
cnxn.commit()
```

### Update and Delete

As with an insert, you must also call `commit` after calling `execute` for an update or delete:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE MyTable SET Col1= 'SomeValue'")
cnxn.commit()
```

### Metadata Discovery

You can use the `getinfo` method to retrieve data such as information about the data source and the capabilities of the driver. The `getinfo` method passes through input to the ODBC `SQLGetInfo` method.

```
cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DATA_SOURCE_NAME)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is even more and better than what I ask!.